# Curly brackets with german keyboard

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, usb, keybindings

Having a usb keyboard in german language connected to the MacBook.

Curly brackets are on <kbd>Alt+Gr+7</kbd> / <kbd>Alt+Gr+0</kbd> on German keyboards, but pressing these keys gives me different characters.

So how can I type curly brackets on a german keyboard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two German key bindings in macOS:

- "German", with <kbd>{</kbd>/<kbd>}</kbd> on <kbd>Opt/Alt</kbd>-<kbd>8</kbd>/<kbd>9</kbd>
- "German - Standard", with <kbd>{</kbd>/<kbd>}</kbd> on <kbd>Opt/Alt</kbd>-<kbd>7</kbd>/<kbd>0</kbd>

Make sure you use the key combinations matching the key bindings.

You can set your layout to German Standard in System Settings > Keyboard > Text Input > Edit > Input Sources